# Facebook Events appear on Google Map

Tags: facebook, events, google-maps

is there a way I can make events on the standard Facebook events app appear on a custom Google Map I've created?

Any tips would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Given you have the `user_events` permission, you can access the locations like so:

```
FB.api("/me/events", function(events) {
    if(events.error) 
         console.error(events);

    var map = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=14&size=512x512&maptype=roadmap&sensor=false";

    for(var i = 0; i < events.data.length; i++) {
        var point = "&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C";
        point += (events.data[i].venue.latitude + "," + events.data[i].venue.longitude);
        map   += point;
    }

    var img = document.createElement("IMG");
    img.src = map;
    document.body.appendChild(img);
});
```

I didn't test it, but this should be enough to show an example of how to access the API in the browser and render a map with it's information. This is using Google Maps static API.

Answer (score 0):

I just created a python script, [source here](https://github.com/DaWe35/Facebook-event-crawler).

It queries the given facebook page and it's events and puts the data into a MySQL table. It also contains a Geo-cache library, which combines a local database with the Google Maps Geocoding API, so you can query the longitude and the latitude of the events very fast.